# Is there a term for tool use in animals?

Tags: zoology, ethology

Is there a technical/scientific term that scientists use to refer to tool making abilities found in certain types of animals?

Reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_cognition#Tool_and_weapon_use

Comment: Note that you actually ask two different questions here - 'tool use' and 'tool making' are two different behaviours. Although, to the best of my knowledge, the correct terms for them (whatever the species) are 'tool use' and 'tool making' respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having read [this article](http://www.eva.mpg.de/primat/staff/boesch/pdf/fol_prim_tool_use_making.pdf) on tool use in Chimpanzees in full, I am inclined to say that if such a term existed then either the article itself or the titles of any of the 30 articles referenced would have included it.

Searching a couple of online biological dictionaries and ethology sites hasn't yielded anything either, therefore until someone else points out that I'm missing the obvious I'd say you're free to coin the term yourself!

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen anything more formal than just plain "tool use". For instance, see the article "[The Ecological Significance of Tool Use in New Caledonian Crows](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1192053)"

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. Appreciate it. Was hoping for a "scientific term" if such a thing exists. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I think **"tool use"** could serve as a good term on it's own, don't you think?

Comment: Yea... But I am looking for a phrase which confuses the layman. :-p haha.

Comment: :-) All these years I've wondered why an "ophthalmologist" couldn't just be called "eye doctor"... Let's please just call "tool use" as "tool use". No more Latin, Greek. Let's just stick to the current state of English.